# Doing a course on replit and confused when I run this code

Tags: python

When ever I run this code and I type in Black shouldn't the program say nice and double nice. I am a complete noob and trying to understand if and elif statements. Whenever I type in Black it just says double nice but since it is two if statements in a row then shouldn't the program print both results.

```
car = input("What color is the car? ")

if car == "Red":
    print("nice")
if car == "Black":
    print("double nice")
```

I explained it above

Comment: `if` part isn't True, why would you think it would execute?

Comment: @matszwecja my bad i typed the code in wrong I had two ifs not an if and an elif I just changed it

Comment: @TomKarzes I thoguht if there are two if statements in a row testing the same condition and I put Black it would print both anwsers ?

Comment: @TomKarzes oh okay I was just looking up anwsers for diffrent things on chatgpt and thats what it said I will take a look at if and elif statements again. Thx for the help.

Comment: @Stef If you have a sequence of `if` statements, with no `elif` or `else`, all it does is (1) test the first condition, and execute the first body if and only if the first condition is true, then (2) test the second condition, and execute the second body if and only if the second condition is true.  It's exactly what you'd expect it to do and it is as simple as it could possibly be.

Answer (score 0):

You typed in 'Black', so the value of `car` is now `Black`.

```
if car == "Red":
    print("nice")
```

Means "print `nice` if the value of car is `Red`. But the value of car is not `Red`. So the program doesn't print `nice`.

`elif` means "else" (i.e., **otherwise**, that is, if the previous `if` was **not** true), then...

```
elif car == "Black":
    print("double nice")
```

"Print `double nice` if the value of `car` is `Black`". And it is! So the program prints `double nice`.

To sum up:

"Print `nice` if the value of `car` is `Red`. Otherwise, print `double nice` if the value of `car` is `Black`."

The program will only ever print at most one of `nice` or `double nice`. If the vlaue of `car` is `Green` for example, it will print nothing.